Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit (Sepolia test Network)
I will summarise my question.
I have first deployed successfully the smart contract from my account address in Sepolia test network. Then, when I wanted to call a function of that deployed contract, I have this error:
"cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit". "UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT"
The parameter of the function that I want to call is a deployed contract address that implement a Interface.
I have tried to fix this problem on my own searching on the internet, but I couldn't. I have tried to add a gas limit manually to the transection, but it did not work. I used Hardhat for this project and maybe something is wrong with the configuration.
Please, help!
"Deploy.js" file:
const hre = require("hardhat");
const ethers = hre.ethers;

async function main() {
 // The address of the winner contract that we want to call
  const winnerContractAddress = "0xcF469d3BEB3Fc24cEe979eFf83BE33ed50988502";
  // Get the EventWinner contract factory from the hardhat config
  const EventWinner = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("EventWinner");
  // Deploy the EventWinner contract to the blockchain
  const eventWinner = await EventWinner.deploy();

  // Wait for the contract to be deployed
  await eventWinner.deployed();

  // Log the address of the deployed contract to the console
  console.log(`contract is deployed to ${eventWinner.address}`);

  // Call the callWinner function of the EventWinner contract and pass in the address of the winner contract
 
  const tx = await eventWinner.callWinner(winnerContractAddress);
 
  // Wait for the transaction to be confirmed on the blockchain
  await tx.wait();
}

// Call the main function and catch any errors
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});

"Contract.sol" file:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.27;

interface ContractWinner{
    function attempt()external;
}

contract EventWinner{
    // Function to call the attempt function on the ContractWinner instance at the given address
    function callWinner(address winnerContractAddress) external{
        ContractWinner(winnerContractAddress).attempt();
    }
}

"hardhat.config.js" file:
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  
  solidity: "0.8.27",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: process.env.RPC_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY]
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      sepolia: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
    },
  },
};


Can you show me the log message?
I mean, can you check the deployed eventWinner contract address in the log message?

Hello. That is the log message: "Reason: 'execution reverted',
Code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT',
Method: 'estimateGas',
Transaction:  { from: '0x1076F189687Bfe1b0A8C632098c45B9e052FaC45',
to: '0xEa75eB8670c12488d081479893b1C6B62f9039E7',
data: '0xbef097e2000000000000000000000000cf469d3beb3fc24cee979eff83be33ed50988502',
accessList: null" Thank you!

0x1076F189687Bfe1b0A8C632098c45B9e052FaC45 is my account address. 0xEa75eB8670c12488d081479893b1C6B62f9039E7 is the EventWinner contract address. 0xcF469d3BEB3Fc24cEe979eFf83BE33ed50988502 is a deployed contract address that implement a Interface

You need to use low-level call() function instead of direct attempt() function.
The call() function with abi.encodeWithSignature() ensures the function call is properly encoded and sent to the target contract, increasing the chances of successful execution.
This is what I have just done.
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x333BA72B7b3736e310B325cBEDBAd8e9Af752648#code
Please check. You can find updated contract file there, and can call the function.
And this is the deploy.ts script.
import { ethers } from 'hardhat'

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  const EventWinner = await ethers.getContractFactory("EventWinner");
  const eventWinner = await EventWinner.deploy();
  await eventWinner.waitForDeployment();
  
  console.log(`EventWinner deployed to: ${await eventWinner.getAddress()}`);

  const winnerContractAddress = "0xcF469d3BEB3Fc24cEe979eFf83BE33ed50988502";
  const tx = await eventWinner.callWinner(winnerContractAddress);

  console.log("Transaction hash:", tx.hash);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exitCode = 1
  })


Yes, it worked. Now I undertsand the code. Thank you very much for your help!
